# Regex Lookahead to match based on indented text

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to match lines that start with a specific string (in this example "interface") if there is a another defined text (here "switchport mode access") in the following indented lines.

Example data:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description abc
 bla
 switchport mode access
 xyz
 abc
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
 xyz
 abc
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
 description Test
 switchport mode access
 xyz
 abc
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/5
 description
```

Should match:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
```

I tried:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1\/0\/[0-9](?=(\n|.)*switchport mode access)
```

But this checks all the lines below an interface, so it does match:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/3
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/4
```

How can I make the lookahead only work until there is a line that doesnt start with a whitespace?

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this look ahead based expression that will match your desired string only if it is followed by `switchport mode access` without `interface GigabitEthernet` appearing in between,

```
interface GigabitEthernet1.*(?=(?:(?!interface GigabitEthernet1)[\w\W])*switchport mode access)
```

`interface GigabitEthernet1.*` matches till end of line only if it is followed by `switchport mode access` while there is no occurrence of `interface GigabitEthernet1` in between using `(?=(?:(?!interface GigabitEthernet1)[\w\W])*switchport mode access)` positive look ahead

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Iuh8AC/1)**

Edit: Thanks to Anubhav's suggestion in comments for even a better performing regex,

```
^interface GigabitEthernet1\/0\/[0-9](?=(?:(?!\ninterface GigabitEthernet1\/0\/[0-9])[\s\S])*switchport mode access)
```

**[Faster regex as suggested by Anubhava](https://regex101.com/r/Iuh8AC/2)**

Comment: ++ to make it even faster use: `^interface GigabitEthernet1\/0\/[0-9](?=(?:(?!\ninterface GigabitEthernet1\/0\/[0-9])[\s\S])*switchport mode access)`

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks Anubhav, that's a considerate improvement almost double the speed. I appreciate your input for improving my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Capture the contents of Group 1 after using the following regex:

```
(interface GigabitEthernet.*)(?:(?!interface GigabitEthernet)[\s\S])*switchport mode access
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hawPfE/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `(interface GigabitEthernet.*)` - [**Tempered Greedy Token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5331061) - matches `interface GigabitEthernet` followed by 0+ occurrences of any character until the newline character and captures this whole match in group 1
- `(?:(?!interface GigabitEthernet)[\s\S])*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that does not begin with the sub-string `interface GigabitEthernet`
- `switchport mode access` - matches `switchport mode access`